# Where can I find a complete bibliography for Elektra?

Tags: marvel

Anyone knows where to find a complete bibliography of [Elektra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektra_%28comics%29). The wikipedia article is of little use and Google didn't help that much...

A bibliography with timeline would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Her [page](http://comicbookdb.com/character.php?ID=2329) on the Comic Book Database has a [list of every one of her appearances](http://comicbookdb.com/character_chron.php?ID=2329) in chronological/publishing order.

I found this [archived message board page](http://revision3.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-8438.html) where someone asks the same question. Judging by what that site says and my own limited knowledge of the character, it seems like the essential Elektra stories are:

- ***Daredevil*** #168-169, 1981
- ***Daredevil*** #174-182, 1981-1982
- ***Daredevil*** #190, 1983
- ***Elektra: Assassin*** #1-8, 1986-1987
- ***Elektra*** volume 3 #1-6, 2001-2002
- ***Wolverine*** volume 3 #20-31: "Enemy of the State"/"Agent of S.H.I.E.L.D.", 2004-2005
- ***Daredevil*** volume 2 #76-81: "The Murdock Papers", 2005-2006
- ***Dark Reign: Elektra*** #1-5, 2009

In the time leading up to the Dark Reign: Elektra mini, [Elektra was impersonated by a Skrull](http://comicbookdb.com/character_chron.php?ID=25824) as part of the larger Secret Invasion storyline that Marvel did. While eventually revealed to not be Elektra, these issues constitute an important event in the character's history.

- ***New Avengers*** #27-31: "Revolution", 2007
- ***New Avengers*** #32: "The Trust, part one", 2007

Comment: @Dr G Heads up, Elektra: Assassin is being re-released in a hardcover format in November. Details: http://ifanboy.com/articles/heads-up-marvel-comics-previews-november-2011/

Answer (score 7):

Marvel's [detail page for Elektra](http://marvel.com/comic_books/browse/character/1009288/elektra) lists 109 appearances that can be sorted oldest to newest.  I don't know if it's more or less complete than other possible sources like, say, Comicvine.

Comment: It seems to be less complete. It doesn't list Elektra: Assassin.